# Added record cannot be deleted in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, c#, jqgrid

Can anyone help me out. I've tried a lot of solutions I found but none of it works for me. The scenario is that I was able to add a record in my JQGrid by using the below code:

```
 var tableData = [];
 tableData = {  Id: $("#dllName").val(),
                EarningDeductionSetupId: $("#dllName").val(),
                Name: selectedText,
                Description: $("#lblDescription").text(),
                Amount: $("#txtAmount").val()
             }

 jQuery("#tblDataTable").jqGrid('addRowData', 'myrowid', tableData, 'last');
```

So the data was added and was shown in my table (jqgrid). The problem now is that when I want to remove the data that I added, the data was not removed. I use the code below:

```
  function RemoveRecord(rowId) {
       $('#tblOtherDeductionsAdj').jqGrid('delRowData', rowId);
  }
```

The RemoveRecord function was called as formatter in my Jqgrid as below:

```
function OtherDeductionsDeleteAdjLink(rowObject) {

return "<a id=\'DeleteLink'\ style=\"cursor:pointer\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"  onclick=\"ModalConfirmation('" + MODAL_HEADER + "','"
    + MSG_CONFIRM_DELETE_REC + "','RemoveRecord(" + **rowObject.Id** + ");', 'function');\"></a>";
 }
```

**take note:**
I was able to delete the record using the same code when the loaded data was from the database. I encounter the issue once I added a record locally.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= 4.7? If possible post more code - by example the code of  ModalConfirmation and etc. Best will be if you post demo code in jsfiddle